# Iphone SDK: Use the same UIImageView at different places in a UIIView?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, subview

I would add the same `UIImageView` at different places to my View.

So I could make ten `UIImageViews` with the same image but with other names. But I got ca. 50 `UIImageViews`.

I make my UIImageView with this code:

Code:

```
CGRect dragRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 70.0, 70.0); 
dragRect.origin = CGPointMake(10, 300); 

UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:dragRect];
[image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Apple.png"]];

[self.view addSubview:image;
```

Now I would like to change my `dracRect.origin` point and make a new `UIImageView` with another name. I would do this in a `for` loop. Is this possible?

Code:

```
int x;
for (x=0; x>=3; x=x+1) {

  CGRect dragRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 70.0, 70.0); 
  //x koordinate wird immer 10 grösser 
  dragRect.origin = CGPointMake(x*10, 300);  

  //image1, image2, image3
  NSString *string1 = [[string1 alloc] initWithFormat:@"image%d",x]; 

  UIImageView *string1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:dragRect];
  [string1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Apple.png"]];

  [self.view addSubview:string1;
}
```

**Update:**

I tried it with `image%i` and with `image%d` but I get an error:

> conflicting types of 'string1'

Answer (score 0):

did you try it?
it should work. perhaps you have to release your UIImageView after you added the Subview, but i am not sure. i would bring the origin-calculation also in the CGRectMake but shouldn't be important.
and don't you have to write: ...initWithFormat:@"image%i",x ?
not sure, i am a xcode noob... :)
i did something similar in an non-iphone project with matrices. but it's not possible to make matrices in the iphone sdk i believe.

Comment: your NSString and your UIImageView objects have the same name! i think independent from other errors this double naming can't work. try it with different names.

Comment: But this is what i want... my UIImageView should have the name of my string, because the string change every time..

Comment: why you don't give tags instead of names? i am even not sure what you mean with names and for what you want us this names.